# asp.net mvc 4 login cookies not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am using this login method to create cookies as session works fine. but cookies is not working. is there any problem here in the code regarding cookies.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(login a) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        Database1Entities1 b = new Database1Entities1();
        var obj = b.registras.Where(m => m.email.Equals(a.email) && m.pass.Equals(a.pass)).FirstOrDefault();
        if(obj != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(a.email, a.RememberMe);
            Session["UserID"] = obj.Id.ToString();
            Session["UserName"] = obj.name.ToString();
            if (a.RememberMe) 
            {
               HttpCookie usercookie = new HttpCookie("UserIDa");
               usercookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
               usercookie.Values.Add("email",a.email);
               usercookie.Values.Add("pass",a.pass);
               HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(usercookie);
               // var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,a.email,DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), a.RememberMe,"", "/");
               // HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                //Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
               //HttpCookie newcook = Request.Cookies["UserIDa"];
               HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("UserIDa");

            }
            ViewBag.message = "congratz u login";
            return RedirectToAction("welcome","Home");
        }
        else { }
    }
    return View(a);
}
```

Comment: `but cookies is not running` what does this mean? And why you are adding password to the cookie

Comment: I am a newbie so I dont know

Comment: If you don't know what issue you are facing how would we know? If issue is not known when what are we supposed to solve?

Comment: whats the problem you are facing,whats the error you need to specify that first.

Comment: the problem is that the cookies are not working i.e when I closed the browser and reopen it requires login again eventhough I pressed remember me check.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please read above

Comment: http://www.howtoasp.net/asp-net-security-tutorials/how-to-use-persistent-cookies-with-forms-authentication-in-asp-net-in-c/